# Passing a value into a class to be used when the class is instantiated in Swift

Tags: class, swift, instance

When creating an instance of a custom class, I want to pass a value back into the class declaration, to be used when it's instantiated.

I tried doing this through a property, but that doesn't work. What is the correct way to achieve this?

(Apologies if I'm not wording the question quite right, but hopefully the code below makes my question clear.)

```
class hello {
    let indexInArray: Int!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        println("This is hello number \(indexInArray).")
    }
}

for index in 0..<4 {
    let singleHello = hello()
    singleHello.indexInArray = index
}
```

The desired output:

```
// This is hello number 0.
// This is hello number 1.
// This is hello number 2.
// This is hello number 3.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this is what you're after:

```
class Hello : HelloSuperClass {
    // Note - this no longer has to be declared as an implicitly unwrapped optional.
    let index: Int

    // Create a new designated initialiser that takes the frame and index as arguments.
    init(frame: CGRect, index: Int) {
        self.index = index
        super.init(frame: frame)
        println("This is hello number \(self.index).")
    }
}

for i in 0..<4 {
    let singleHello = Hello(frame: CGRect(), index: i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a designated initialiser, such as:

```
init(#index: Int) {
    super.init()
    println("This is hello number \(index).")
}
```

and then...

```
for index in 0..<4 {
    let singleHello = hello(index: index)
}
```

So that when you initialise, you can pass in your index as a variable. If you want the frame, you can go ahead and do `init(frame: CGRect, index: Int) {}`